# How to run a console through SSH client and keep it open?

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, nodejs

I have a node application in development in a ubuntu server through SSH connection, I'm using bitvise ssh client, and running `node server.js` through its GUI terminal.

But then when I exit the ssh client, the server terminal is closed remotely, how can I keep it open? I'm not sure if the question is related to this specific client or to SSH in general.

Comment: Lookup how to use the "screen" application (among others), running on the server, to keep a virtual terminal open between connections. 'screen' is included with desktop and server flavors of Ubuntu - you probably already have it installed. Try `man screen`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use nohup command ending by &. So your node command will be like this :

```
nohup node server.js &
```

Note that all output of your node command will be written into nohup.log file.
Also consider using systemd config to keep this script running into a production server.